# Display warning icon in MessageBox

Tags: icons, messagebox

I can't show any icon in MessageBox, I'm using material theme and ExtJS 7 CE

`Ext.Msg.show({ title: 'My Title', message: 'My Message', width: 340, icon: Ext.MessageBox.INFO, buttons: Ext.MessageBox.OK, });`

Tried in Sencha Fiddle, still no luck, please help

Comment: Do you experience this with `classic` or `modern` toolkit?

Comment: Hello Peter, with modern toolkit

Comment: As far as I see, this works in ExtJS 7 only in `classic`. If you set the `icon` property as you do in `modern`, it will think it is a path to an image, and not a CSS style. Since `Ext.MessageBox.INFO` simple resolves to `x-msgbox-info`, this will result in a 404 not found, check in a Fiddle, switch between `classic` and `modern` and check for errors in console.

Comment: I don't know whether this is a bug or an intended behaviour, but as a matter of fact, the documentation for [classic](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.6.0/classic/Ext.window.MessageBox.html#cfg-icon) also says that this is a path. Which of course raises the question why does it work as a CSS class in `classic`, but it does in fact.

Comment: Thank you for the information, how should it be done using modern? if I choose a path to an image, the image is repeated and it does not work with background width and height...

Comment: I don't really know, I tried to find a solution but could not, that's why I have not posted an answer. I tried using `iconCls` but then the icon is not rendered as it should. The documentation is not clear to me, it actually does contradict the source code itself.